# Bind Xaml bitmap image

Tags: c#, xaml, bitmap, bind

I have bitmap image variable and i want to bind it to my xaml window.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
        thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] resources = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
        var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("SplashDemo.Resources.Untitled-100000.png");
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream);
```

And this is my xaml code

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="210" Margin="35,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335">
    </Image>
```

can u assist me binding this bitmap variable to this xaml image by C# code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to set it from C# code and not from inside XAML, you should use this easy solution [described further on the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx):

```
string path = "Resources/Untitled-100000.png";
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
image.Source = bitmap;
```

But first, you need to give your `Image` a name so you can reference it from c#:

```
<Image x:Name="image" ... />
```

No need to reference Windows Forms classes. 
If you insist on having the Image embedded into your Assembly, you need the following more lengthy code to load the image:

```
string path = "SplashDemo.Resources.Untitled-100000.png";
using (Stream fileStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
{
    PngBitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(fileStream,
        BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    ImageSource imageSource = bitmapDecoder.Frames[0];
    image.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Comment: The point is that i want to make a Timer who changes this picture like slideshow. I made a timer, but i dont know how to change the image by C# code

Comment: the code I posted should work in exactly that scenario. do you need an example?

Comment: yes please, but what about if the image is embedded in the assembly?

Comment: I found the solution if you want to have the `BuildAction` as `EmbeddedResource`. Posting.

Comment: This works so good, thanks mate for helping me. I spent ~4 hours to do it (i lack of experience), you saved my brain.

Comment: thanks, I'm glad I could help. By the way, it's possible to upvote an answer in addition to accepting it (by clicking the up arrow).

Comment: not enough reputation, imma vote up all answers (when i get enough rep) that helps me now and in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code:

```
// Winforms Image we want to get the WPF Image from...
System.Drawing.Image imgWinForms = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("test.png");

// ImageSource ...
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

// Save to a memory stream...
imgWinForms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

// Rewind the stream...    
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Tell the WPF image to use this stream...
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
```

[Click here to view reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/833ca60f-6a11-4836-bb2b-ef779dfe3ff0/)

Comment: You are welcome, the way of thanking on this forum is either an up-vote or accepting as answer.

Comment: why use a `MemoryStream` and reference `System.Drawing.Image` when there is a more direct and simple way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, right click your image in your project and set the `Build Action` to `Resource`.  Assuming your image is called `MyImage.jpg` and is in a `Resources` folder in your project, you should be able to reference it directly in your `xaml` without using any C# code. Like this:

```
<Image Source="/Resources/MyImage.jpg" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="210" 
    Margin="35,10,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="335">
</Image>
```

Comment: not to nitpick, but the OP did specifically ask about how this can be done in C#.