# How to draw/overlay an image file to a bitmap image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, overlay

I have a video feed from a Kinect sensor hosted by an image stored as a bitmap. My question is how do I overlay an image, for example a `.png` on to the video feed.

The video feed is shown like show below as bitmap source, I know how to draw a line to the bitmap but how do I draw an image from resources to the it?

```
KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);
```

Below is a mock up of what I'm trying to achieve by placing the image over the video feed:

[image: The boxing bag is the image I want to overlay to the video feed.]

Updated implementation of drawing method,I don't think this is the correct implementation also I'm getting invalid argument error when adding image path to `.DrawImage`:

```
void myKinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {

                if (colorFrame == null) return;
                byte[] colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);

                 KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel);

                Rect destRect2;

               //drawing image overlay to video feed
                 var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                 var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
                 drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel),
                                           new Rect(new Size(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height)));
                 drawingContext.DrawImage("Images/boxbag.jpg", destRect2);
                 drawingContext.Close();
                 var mergedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                 mergedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

                 KinectVideo.Source = mergedImage; 


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create merged image you can use [`DrawingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that gives you methods like `DrawText` or `DrawImage` and then render it using `RenderTargetBitmap.Render`:

```
var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel), 
                          new Rect(new Size(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height)));
var overlayImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/boxbag.jpg"));
drawingContext.DrawImage(overlayImage, 
                          new Rect(x, y, overlayImage.Width, overlayImage.Height));
drawingContext.Close();
var mergedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
mergedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

KinectVideo.Source = mergedImage;
```

Comment: Okay, So I put this code after my video source and set `drawingContext.DrawImage(KinectVideo, destRect1);` and `drawingContext.DrawImage(PunchBag, destRect1);` and this will draw the image onto the feed or am Igetting this wrong?

Comment: Okay, I tried the updated code but this line is confusing me, ` drawingContext.DrawImage("Images/bbag.jpg", destRect2);`  what is destRect2, do I have to declare it also is the path to the image the correct parameter for image 2?

Comment: The region in which to draw bitmapSource. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606804(v=vs.110).aspx That means you can draw it where you want in the target and potentially just a portion of it from top/left. Set X/Y to where you want, Width/Height to match your overlay image dimensions.

Comment: From my answer, @dkozl and the other answerer I think you have many approaches for a solution to your problem. If you still can't get it right, then update your question but with a code block this time, not only 1 line of code.

Comment: @Aybe @dkozl I updated my question to show how I'm trying to implement your solution.Could you show me where I'm going wrong with it? I'm getting invalid arguments for the `drawingContext.DrawImage(image2, destRect2);` also.

Comment: `image2` is just a place holder for your overlay image. Check my update.

Comment: That's what I was going to write, you can't put the path to the image, you need to create a `BitmapImage` from it.

Comment: Okay I have a better understanding of this now but when I implemented the new solution @dkozl the uri gives an error for the image. I get this error `'System.UriFormatException'` but it doesn't seem to be wrong format? This is how I set uri:  `var overlayImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/boxbag.png"));`

Comment: the path to the file is correct as far as I can tell,any idea why its giving a `.UriFormatException` ? Should I be calling the image differently?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want display an `Image` on top of another UI control, then you can either just declare one *after* the other UI elements, or set the `Panel.ZIndex` property:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="Black" />
    <Image Source="/AppName;component/Images/ImageName.jpg" Width="50" Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

Or:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="/AppName;component/Images/ImageName.jpg" 
        Width="50" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    <Border Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

To find out how to data bind a `BitmapImage` to an `Image.ItemsSource` property, please see the [Bind Xaml bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276438/bind-xaml-bitmap-image) question here on StackOverflow. To position the `Image` in a specific place, you can either use the `Image.Margin` property or put it in a `Canvas` and use the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties.