# Draw Sign on selected Point

Tags: c#, wpf, point, shapes

I'm programming a distance measurement program for my kinect sensor. To measure the distance the user select two points in a depth image and the program displays the distance between the two points.

To make it easier for the user to remember, which points he has selected, I now want to mark the selected points with a sign in the depth image and connect the two points by a line.

I now know that there is a class called Ellipse Class, which allows to draw a ellipse, but I don't know how to draw them in a specific image.

So in my program I get the coordinates of the selected points by a MouseButtonState-Event and store the relative coordinates to the depth Image in a variable, so I can just read out the x and y coordinate.

```
myMousePosition = e.GetPosition(DepthImage);
```

I also found a way to draw a line in the XAML file. But still I don't know how to draw a small circle at a given point and connect the two points with a line in C# code. Does somebody know how to solve this.

Edit: I tried to draw a line in the depth image, with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
    public void drawDistance(double xp1, double yp1, double xp2, double yp2)
    {
        double Xpos1 = xp1;
        double Ypos1 = yp1;
        double Xpos2 = yp2;
        double Ypos2 = yp2;
        myLine = new Line();
        myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        myLine.X1 = Xpos1;
        myLine.Y1 = Ypos1;
        myLine.X2 = Xpos2;
        myLine.Y2 = Ypos2;
        myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        DepthImage.Child.Add(myLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to achieve this by overlaying and merging the markers. See: [How to draw/overlay an image file to a bitmap image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915705/how-to-draw-overlay-an-image-file-to-a-bitmap-image)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I still do not understand how I can draw a line or an ellipse in my image. I posted some code I tried to use, but it didn't worked. Visual Studio just tells me: 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'Child' and no extension method 'Child' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)